# cassandra tunnel failing

Tags: linux, ssh-tunneling

I am having cassandra community edition 3.11.13 running on private subnet in AWS. I am trying to create tunnel to the cassandra using below commands.

```
ssh -vvv -N -L 9042:cass-ip:9042 username@jumphost-ip
ssh -vvv -N -L 9160:cass-ip:9160 username@jumphost-ip
```

Now with nc command i can see connection is fine.

```
nc -dvzw50 localhost 9160
Connection to localhost 9160 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

nc -dvzw50 localhost 9042
Connection to localhost 9042 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But when i try to run cqlsh localhost it is giving me operation timed out.
Below is the output when i run ssh tunnel command.

```
debug2: channel 2: chan_shutdown_write: shutdown() failed for fd 7: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: On your jumphost, is the command `nc -vz cass-ip 9042` successful? (use the ip address instead of "cass-ip", just like your example ssh tunnel commands)  How about when you use the port 9160 instead of 9042?

Comment: Yes on jumphost it is successful too. I am using Ip address only, (just posted as cass-ip )